# How much does the Soothing Bag increase the pokemon's happiness value?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Happiness values can be between 0-255. My question is simple.

How much does the soothing bag in super training increase the happiness value by?

Comment: According to [this](http://ap.ign.com/en/news/9578/pokemon-x-and-y-what-the-heck-is-super-training-), you need to hit it 250 times to make your Pokemon 'slightly' friendlier, although there are mixed reports around the net as to how much 'slightly' is: some say their Eevee evolved straight after level up, and other's Riolu didn't

Comment: @Robotnik - Yeah, even I have experienced similar varying effects. Put up the question to see if someone has figured out actual numbers.

Comment: You're likely not going to get exact numbers. Unlike things like IV, there's no easy way to tell the exact values for happiness as there's no effect on stats to derive it mathematically. There is someone in Laverre City who can check happiness and give you an approximation in general ranges. I haven't been able to find a chart of the messages she gives in relation to happiness though. If someone were to compile a chart, then they could figure out the happiness increase.

Comment: @Tarkenfire - I put this question up, just incase somebody knew. I might juts take it up as a project and try and figure it out myself sometime in the near future. Atleast until then I will let the question stay until someone figures it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Happiness#Generation_VI), the soothing bag raises your Pokemon's happiness by 20 up to a max of 255. This value is not affected by the Luxury Ball, the Soothing Bell, or your Pokemon's current happiness value.

Comment: I think you mean to say that the Soothing Bag raises the Pokemon's happiness by a maximum of 20.

Comment: @jerry I actually meant that the bag raises happiness by 20, **up to** a maximum of 255. Still, my original wording was incorrect, so I changed it.

Comment: Hmm, I would've worded it another way for sure, because I think it could be confusing to someone who doesn't know about this stuff, especially when happiness is a hidden mechanic and the limit of happiness points is independent on the method used to increase it.